# extending jQuery functionality specifics on variations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand I can extend jQuery in two forms:

1)

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    variation1: function(){
        ...           
    }
});

I use this like $(selector).variation1();
```

2)

and custom function

```
jQuery.variation2 = {
    something: function(){
        var execute = function(){
            ...
        }
    }
}

I use this like $.variation2.something()
```

My questions are:

1. In the first case, I was unable to call functions without a selector; this code caused errors $.variation1(); Is this correct? meaning, is there a way to call these functions without an element selector?
2. In the second case, how could I initialize variation2 with options? The reason I ask this is because in MooTools, when creating a class, we can initialize the class like:

var jsClass = new Class({
    Implements: [Options],
        options: {
        },
        initialize: function(options){
            this.setOptions(options);
        } 
    });

we call it, and initialize with custom options like

new jsClass({option1: this, option2: that})

So in the MooTools example the class instance executes options by default. Going back to the question, is there a way to do similar in jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One depends on a jQuery instance and the other doesn't. Use what's most convenient for each situation. It is similar to "public" vs "static" method.

Comment: elclanrs very interesting. Help me clarify: if PUBLIC, I can use it anywhere there is jQuery library? like in the webpage with jQuery defined then call $(selector).variation1();  STATIC, I can only used inside the function brackets that wrap this definition? like jQuery(document).ready(function($) { jQuery.variation2 = { ...}  $.variation2.comething()...}); and no outside of here?

Comment: `jQuery.fn == jQuery.prototype`. If you add methods to the prototype they depend on an instance. If you attach methods to the constructor they are like "static" methods, they shouldn't depend on an instance. Most of time you want to add methods to the prototype. Adding methods to the constructor isn't ideal nor necessary, as you can create your own object to hold these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two variations are distinct as you have noticed. `jQuery.fn` provides the set of functions that are applied to a jQuery `QuerySet` object (the result of applying a jQuery selector). `jQuery.*` could simply be thought of as global static objects, including (sometimes) functions that are accessible to anyone who has access to the jQuery object.

To initialize variation 2, I would do something like:

```
jQuery.variation2 = (function() {
    var a = ...;
    var b = ...; // other initialization
    return {
        something: function() {
            ...
        },  ...
    };
})();
```

You could use closures in similar ways to provide initialized code.

Comment: So how would I pass argument to set the variables?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were looking for a place where initialization code would run. You could return getter/setter/init methods as part of the `{ ... }` object you are returning, I suppose.